# Getting translated string through a variable

Tags: multi-language, translation

I am translating a website into different languages, and I have the following problem:

Through the backend, user can select via a dropdown, a value (text string) from a list of 50 options.
This dropdown is stored in a custom field (by the way, managed with ACF PRO).

When a user visits the translated version of the site, I would like to display the translation of that text string.

At first I thought that using

```
$options_obj = get_field_object('user_options');
$options_value = get_field('user_options');
$options_label = $options_obj['choices'][$options_value];

echo __($options_label, 'my_text_domain');
```

And I put the 50 text strings translation (corresponding to all the selectable options) in a po / mo file, **but as we know this won't work**. Gettext don't translate variables.

How I could get the translated string?
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want the dropdown in the backoffice alsways to be in the base language, while on the frontend the translated string should appear?

Comment: PO/MO files designed for one language per site. In a single site WPML translate those option by filtering option value.

Comment: @cjbj you are right!

Comment: @Sumit can you explain better how to get it? I don't want the user to choose three times the same option (one per language).

Comment: Don't use variables for gettext calls - I strongly suggest reading [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305035833/http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: @Capiedge So the site might be in Spanish, the option page in French, but the dropdown should still be in English?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic The reason for this question is just because I already know about don't use variables in gettext calls (in fact, yesterday I've read the article that you link) and I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: My bad, skim read, apologies.

Comment: I have an idea and will post a suggestion as soon as I can.

Comment: @cjbj Not exactly. The site (frontend) is in Spanish, French and English. But in the backend, the user works only in one language (i.e. Spanish), always the same, and therefore this dropdown always appear only in Spanish. The aim is that the text string displayed on the frontend, change depending on the selected language. In the database the text string will only be saved in one language (Spanish).

Comment: In that case the solution is simple. See below.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I will be glad of read your suggestion ;) I'm really stuck on this question.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic you commented one year ago that maybe there is a way to solve this question. Could you give me some advice, please? Thanks!

Comment: gettext calls on variables should work if the _value_ of the string matches one in a translation file. It's just translators like poedit or WPML won't pick up the string since it's a runtime variable for when you're _generating_ po files

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure whether this is what you want, but if the option page is in one language you can simply put the gettext call in the custom field itself to avoid using variables. For the admin you force the translation to spanish:

```
function wpse227983_force_language ( $locale ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return 'es_ES';
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'wpse227983_force_language' );
```

On the frontend the messages will then be translated in the normal way, supposing that you have a system in place that determines what the language of the page is. If the author sets a custom field for the language, you can use the above filter with a different `if` to force the translation.

Comment: What do you mean with "put the gettext call in the custom field"? This function only changes the $locale variable, depending if you are in the admin or not? I still have the same problem, trying to translate the custom field stored value. I can't catch the way in which you intend to solve the problem.